# Is it possible to position a text depending on the position of the mouse with React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onmousemove

I have a simple div, with a function to obtain the coordinates of the mouse inside this div.

```
<div onMouseMove={this._onMouseMove}></div>
```

This function saves in the state, the coordinates of the div

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedVariables: [],
      mouseCordinates: {x: 0, y: 0}
    };
  }

  _onMouseMove = e => {
    this.setState({x: e.screenX, y: e.screenY});
    console.log(`x: ${e.screenX}, y: ${e.screenY}`);
  }
```

And now I want to draw the variable ***helloWorld*** in this div in these concrete coordinates

```
helloWorld = 'Hello World';

<div onMouseMove={this._onMouseMove}>
  // Into this div it must paint the variable according to the coordinates
</div>
```

This is possible? Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: my question would be a simple: its javascript. Why wouldnt it?  Have you even tried your code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think you do not understand my question.
My code works perfectly but not with what I want to do.

Comment: It looks like you are just wanting to when the mouse moves, have the div follow suit.  On top of that, you want to display some text inside of it?  Well, onMouseMove is monitored only from the div it is assigned, so youd want your canvas or workspace to have the mouse move.  Then you would just need to define a div with a reference to the attribute therein.  Then in your mousemove, would move the div with the approperiate ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the answer below as a starting point:

```
helloWorld = 'Hello World';

<div onMouseMove={this._onMouseMove}>
  // Into this div it must paint the variable according to the coordinates
<div style=`position:relative;left:${this.state.mouseCoordinates.x},
 top:${this.state.mouseCoordinates.y}`>{helloWorld}</div>
</div>
```

I am aware that my styling would be wrong because I'm using x and y coordinates to specify `left` and `top` in a `position:relative`, but I hope you can tweak around that part to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it will be useful to do this.